# Tableau – Using Nested Aggregations to Establish a Weekday/Hour Baseline

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api

**Background Information:** We have an incident time tracker that tracks how long each user spends with a representative before the issue can be closed. We want to determine the average volume of incidents that are being handled for each hour. To say this in another way: We want to get an hourly baseline for each day of the week that will show us the average total call length within the specific time period. Eg: We want to average the total length of every call on Monday from 9AM-10AM for all the weeks in the database, and the same for other hourly intervals.

The simplest way to think of this is that I want AVG(SUM) for the specific time periods, but Tableau does not allow me to do this.

**Tableau Output:**
This is the desired, target visualization that I am looking for from Tableau. 
[image: Tableau Output Grouped by Weekday and Hour]

**SQL Query:**
I have written a SQL query that returns the answer:

[image: SQL code]

We are looking at two columns: start_time (time stamp) and interval_seconds(float)

In the inner query I use the hour_start function which truncates the date/time value to the hour start, so I can group by the hour and day of the week in the outer query.

**SQL Results:**

[image]

**Question:**
Is there a way to solve this problem **ENTIRELY** in Tableau that would get me the result that I am looking for without having to write any SQL code?

**Files Stored on Drive**

CSV File:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4nMLxIVTDc7NEtqWlpHdVozRXc

Tableau Worksheet:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4nMLxIVTDc7M3A4Q0JxbGdlTE0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Level of Detail expressions](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.html) to compute the SUM(interval_seconds) at the hour level and then use AVG to calculate the number you are looking for.

I created a couple of calculations:

`hour` which is defined as: `DATETRUNC('hour',[start_time])`

this should be equivalent to your hour_start(start_time).

and `interval_hours` which is defined as `{FIXED [hour] : SUM([interval_seconds])/3600 }`

This calculates the aggregate for each start_time truncated to the hour.

After this, you simply calculate `AVG(interval_hours)` and use it in your view.

I put a workbook in dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3hfvz8w529g9f46/Interval%20Time%20Baseline.twbx?dl=0

Although the chart looks similar to yours, the numbers I came up with are somewhat different from the "SQL Results" you show. Was the data you provided slightly different?